# MySQLdb Python execute not returning Table

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I've been trying to use python's MySQLdb to execute SQL on a MySQL Database from SSH on my webhost. This program i wrote (on a mac) should print a table, but it doesn't.

Here's my code:

```
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect("my host","my username","my password","my database")

cursor = db.cursor()


cursor.execute('''
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS news;
    CREATE TABLE news
    (
        id int unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
        headline varchar(250) NOT NULL,
        summary varchar(5000) NOT NULL,
        date varchar(50) NOT NULL,
        link varchar(2500) NOT NULL,
        imagelink varchar(2500) NOT NULL,
        category varchar(50) NOT NULL,

        PRIMARY KEY (id)
    );

    insert into news (headline, summary, date, link, imagelink, category)
    values ("The worlds awesomest news source.", "Released by So-and-so , this will be the greatest thing ever.", "Aug. 11", "http://www.google.com/", "http://www.example.com/", "World");

    SELECT summary FROM news WHERE id = 1;
    ''')


results = cursor.fetchall()
print results
```

...  and the output in Mac Terminal is:

`()`

Please tell me what the problem is, and how to fix it. Thank you!

-CJ

Comment: Have you tried separating out each of the SQL commands? i.e. use one execute() call to DROP, another to CREATE, another to INSERT, then finally a fourth one to SELECT. Also after each command, have you tried manually checking that the operation has executed successfully?

Comment: @wookie919 THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU!!!! You saved my life - my partner and i have been getting so frustrated about this - now it Works! I can't express our thanks, but thank you so much!

Comment: LOL, you are very welcome. :) You can reward me by accepting my brief answer, which I will write up soon.

Comment: Will do - just did. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please separate each SQL commands into separate calls to execute().

Combining multiple SQL commands in such a fashion may not work, and also separating out into multiple execute() commands make debugging easier.